# SonarQube Possible Null pointer dereference in Scala pattern matching of Option

Tags: scala, sonarqube, pattern-matching

SonarQube report shows a critical bug

> "A null pointer is dereferenced here.  This will lead to a
>   NullPointerException when the code is executed."

for the below Scala code block

```
val someList = Option(listCommingFromJava.asScala.toList)
someList match {
  case Some(list) =>
        logger.info("List found: {}", list.map(someTransformFunction)) //Sonar Complains here of "Null pointer dereference of ?"
  case None => 
        logger.info("NoListFound")
}
```

logger is for sure initialized. 
I could share the sonar configurations, but I can't see how this code can lead to a null pointer dereference? My own conclusion is that Sonar is wrong in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In [iterableAsScalaIterableConverter](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/convert/DecorateAsScala.scala#L41) we can see that it creates [AsScala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/convert/Decorators.scala#L27) object with reference to the result of [iterableAsScalaIterable](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/convert/AsScalaConverters.scala#L74) which can be `null` if Java `Iterable` reference is `null`. So your `listCommingFromJava` shouldn't be `null`. Otherwise, `listCommingFromJava.asScala` will return `null` and `listCommingFromJava.asScala.toList` will throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, makes sense! However, why isn't the warning reported on that line instead? Is it perhaps because sonar can't distinguish the lines properly as there are no semi-colons?